# how to run cygwin script from java

Tags: java, bash, process, runtime

I'm trying to run a bash script from a Java program I'm writing in windows.  I've been trying to use the Runtime object to get a process to work, and my program compiles and runs without exceptions, but my simple test script, which just makes a directory, is not being executed.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
String cmmd[] = new String[3];
    cmmd[0] = "C:\\cygwin\\bin\\bash.exe";
    cmmd[1] = "cd C:/Users/pro-services/Desktop/projects/github/cygwin";
    cmmd[2] = "bash TEST.sh";

    Runtime rt= Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = rt.exec(cmmd);
```

This is basically a mix of different things I've found in forums around the net, but I guess I just don't really understand what is  happening with the Process class (and I only have a basic idea about the Runtime class).

I also found this, and plugged my own stuff in where I thought it should go:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"C:\\cygwin\\bin\\bash.exe",
                                                    "-c", "c:\\cygwin\\bin\\run.exe -p /bin bash C:\\Users\\pro-services\\Desktop\\projects\\github\\cygwin\\TEST.sh"},
                                      new String[]{"PATH=/cygdrive/c/cygwin/bin"});
```

Here I'm not sure what the `"-c"` and `"-p"` strings represent, but I just went with it.  At first it looked like I could just plug in the sequential commands that I want the Runtime/Process object to execute, in essence creating a  "script" to run my script.  But it now seems that there's more to it...

I'm just shooting in the dark at this point, and I have tried to understand the documentation but I'm lost.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks )))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but I would think:

```
cmmd[0] = "C:/cygwin/bin/bash.exe";
cmmd[1] = "-c";
cmmd[2] = "cd /cygdrive/c/Users/pro-services/Desktop/projects/github/cygwin && bash TEST.sh";
```

Comment: and then just run `Runtime rt= Runtime.getRuntime();
  Process proc = rt.exec(cmmd);`    ?  Mysteriously I still get no result.  Thanks, this does look better.