# Run cygwin script with arguments from java as background process

Tags: javascript, java, bash, command-line, cygwin

I am trying to run cygwin script from java code. I have used following code for same,

```
String[] command = {"cmd.exe","/C","Start","C:/cygwin64/bin/bash","./bin/script.sh","input_file.mkv","I:/video/output.avi"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

it works fine but, instead of calling script from "cmd" as described above. Can we run cygwin bash script directly? I have tried following code but it is not working

```
String[] command = {"C:/cygwin64/bin/bash","./bin/script.sh","input_file.mkv","I:/video/output.avi"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

I am not getting what I am doing wrong. Also I want script to run as background process, so what can we do for same?

Comment: Try remove the first 3 array elements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to run cygwin script from java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623863/how-to-run-cygwin-script-from-java)

Comment: There are lots of examples of how to do this on StackOverflow. This is really a duplicate question. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623863/how-to-run-cygwin-script-from-java

Comment: @pczeus same solution i have tried while running bash script directly, but it is not working. That is why I have posted this question. Also I wanted to run this script as background process. Please post answer if you know it.